# DEoptim parallel options

Tags: r, optimization

Hi I am trying to understand how to get DEoptim to work using parallel processing, but am struggling to get the correct parameters to be put into the function to get it to work...below is a reproducible example (it has a financial context) but it is designed for creating a random portfolio of 7 assets to optimise for ES. It was inspired by this http://mpra.ub.uni-muenchen.de/28187/1/RJwrapper.pdf  and also http://files.meetup.com/1772780/20120201_Ulrich_Parallel_DEoptim.pdf

the second of which does include a parallel option but want to use the unix forking rather than the SOCK clusters.

```
require(quantmod)
require(PerformanceAnalytics)
require(DEoptim)

tickers <- c("^GSPC","^IXIC","^TNX", "DIA","USO","GLD","SLV","UNG","^VIX","F","^FTSE","GS","MS","MSFT","MCD","COKE","AAPL","GOOG","T","C","BHP","RIO","CMG")
getSymbols(tickers)
tickers <- gsub("\\^","",tickers)

x <- lapply(tickers, function(x){ClCl(get(x))})
comb <- na.omit(do.call(merge,x))
colnames(comb) <- paste0(tickers,".cc")

obj <- function(w) {
 if (sum(w) == 0) { w <- w + 1e-2 }
 w <- w / sum(w)
 CVaR <- ES(weights = w,
 method = "gaussian",
 portfolio_method = "component",
 mu = mu,
 sigma = sigma)
 tmp1 <- CVaR$ES
 tmp2 <- max(CVaR$pct_contrib_ES - 0.225, 0)
 out <- tmp1 + 1e3 * tmp2
}

comb1 <- comb[,sample(1:ncol(comb),7)]
no.of.assets <- ncol(comb1)
mu <- colMeans(comb1)
sigma <- cov(comb1)


## The non-parallel version
output <- DEoptim(fn = obj,lower = rep(0, no.of.assets), upper = rep(1, no.of.assets))

## The parallel version that doesn't seem to work...
output <- DEoptim(fn = obj,lower = rep(0, no.of.assets), upper = rep(1, no.of.assets), DEoptim.control(itermax=10000, trace=250, parallelType="parallel", packages=c("PerformanceAnalytics"), parVar=c("mu","sigma")))
```

I get the following error message

```
Error in missing(packages) : 'missing' can only be used for arguments
```

Comment: Try changing parallelType="parallel" to parallelType=1 ? As per ?DEoptim.control

Comment: Your code works with DEoptim from CRAN.  It fails with DEoptim from R-Forge.